# Why does disk read function lead to page fault

Tags: c, memory, osdev

The following function that reads the FAT BPB results in a page fault:

```
fat_bpb* fat_read_bpb(){
    fat_bpb* bpb = kmalloc(sizeof(fat_bpb));
    ide_read_sectors(DRIVE, 1, 6, (uint32)bpb);
    return bpb;
}
```

Single stepping the code shows that the error seems to be at the line `ide_read_sectors(DRIVE, 1, 6, (uint32)bpb);`.

The kmalloc function is based on an internal kmalloc:

```
extern uint32 end;
uint32 placement_address = (uint32)&end;

uint32 kmalloc_int(uint32 sz, int align, uint32 *phys)
{
    // This will eventually call malloc() on the kernel heap.
    // For now, though, we just assign memory at placement_address
    // and increment it by sz. Even when we've coded our kernel
    // heap, this will be useful for use before the heap is initialised.
    if (align == 1 && (placement_address & 0xFFFFF000) )
    {
        // Align the placement address;
        placement_address &= 0xFFFFF000;
        placement_address += 0x1000;
    }
    if (phys)
    {
        *phys = placement_address;
    }
    uint32 tmp = placement_address;
    placement_address += sz;
    return tmp;
}

uint32 kmalloc(uint32 sz)
{
    return kmalloc_int(sz, 0, 0);
}
```

A warning is passed by gcc: `initialization of ‘fat_bpb *’ from ‘uint32’ {aka ‘unsigned int’} makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

Comment: Why magic number `6` in `ide_read_sectors(DRIVE, 1, 6, (uint32)bpb);`?

Comment: Why is `kmalloc` returning an `uint32` instead of e.g. `void *`? Are you possibly building as a 64-bit target, where pointers are 64 bits?

Comment: `(placement_address & 0xFFFFF000)`is suspicious.  I'd expect `placement_address & 0xFFF`

Comment: That if statement isn't invoked by kmalloc, because align and phys are both 0

Comment: A page fault is not an error.

Comment: It seems you might need to read a little bit more about OS and kernel development. What resources are you using to learn about it? What have they told you about virtual memory and pages and page faults?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in reading Bios Parameter Block but...

```
fat_bpb* fat_read_bpb(){
    fat_bpb* bpb = kmalloc(sizeof(fat_bpb));
    ide_read_sectors(DRIVE, 1, 6, (uint32)bpb);
    return bpb;
}
```

Here you acquire a block of memory the size of a BIOS parameter block  (which is far smaller than a disk sector, as it is normally stored in the first block of the partition)

Then you use that pointer to fill it with (I guess here, but from 1 to 6) more than one sector (a BPB is smaller even that a single sector) of data.

You get a page fault.   Normal. That's completely normal..  The way to do this is:

- Try to allocate space for a number of sectors.  Probably one is enough, if you want only to deal with BPB, but a full sector will be filled by the routines, so you will need to allocate space for a full sector, at least.
- Try to set a pointer to the start of the BPB in the sector and use the data as shown.

Then you will get everything fitted in a properly allocated data buffer.